# When and where to update UITableViewCell subview's constraints based on actual widths

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, ios-autolayout

I have a `UITableView` who's cell heights are automatic based on autolayout. Everything works great until I add a subview who's height will vary in a custom way based on the final width of the rendered cell.

In short, I need to show a custom number views, and the number visible will depend how wide the cell is, and the number of views also affects the height.

The problem is I am currently doing the calculation and view manipulation in `layoutSubviews` on the subview in question, but this leads to the table view cell's heights being wildly off. So I believe I need to do the calculation & view adding/removing early enough so autolayout can calculate the correct table view cell height, but late enough so I actually have the correct width that the cell will be to make my calculations.

Forcing `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded` in various places isn't fixing this issue.

Interestingly this is one of the situations where when scrolling the heights start correcting themselves and eventually all cells are the correct height. It seems to be on first load of the table view that things are very off.

Comment: How does the number of views affect the height? Are you maybe showing one row of views on a wide display, and two rows on a narrow display?

Comment: But the width of the cell won't ever change in a UITableView. What you might be better off doing is using two cells (and two reuse identifiers) with fixed layouts. Then move the logic into the `cellForRow` method and dequeue the correct cell type.

Comment: @DonMag I'm showing a series of thumbnails that fit perfectly in the width of the cell. Given their fixed aspect ratio, the number of views that are visible with affect the height of that row.

Comment: @Fogmeister They can change based on rotation and also iPad supports various widths with split-screen etc. Given it needs to support iPhone 5 and the plus devices, there's many widths it needs to support, hence the need to be calculated dynamically and not hardcoded.

Comment: @Sencha ah yes, you're right. So, what is your logic for changing the layout? Put the code in the question.

Comment: @Fogmeister That will take some time as I'll need to distill it down. It's more of a general question about when in the lifecycle can we have access to actual view sizes where it is not to late to make constraint adjustments so that `UITableView` can still adjust it's cells accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

I change the height constraint of a subview in my cell in `layoutSubviews()`, and putting this at the end of `viewDidLoad()` seems to be working well in my tests:

```
    tableView.setNeedsLayout()
    tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    tableView.reloadData()
```

Another option, if your design would permit, would be to tell the table to re-calc its cell heights with:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Assuming your "default" is one "row" of thumbnails, you would see your table rows expand to reveal the 2nd row.

Or, if you don't want to see the animation:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
}
```

but, depending on your actual graphics and design, you might see a flicker taking that approach.